# Run Sql Dump through stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql

Can we run the SQL dump command through a stored procedure/Trigger. I have to create a database on fly when certain events happen in the table.
I have achieved it on mysql command prompt or by workbench, however need a way to do it through procedure or trigger.